# Distribute test sources in modularized project

Tags: android, testing, gradle, architecture

I use this architecture in my android app inspired by [Jeroen Mols](https://jeroenmols.com/blog/2019/03/18/modularizationarchitecture/):

[image: app architecture]

Each module contains its own unit tests independent if it's a feature or library module.

Currently, I have to duplicate code like my testing rules as I didn't find a way to propagate test code from my core module into the module's tests.

This is possible for production code of cource but also for testing? What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new module, say `test-shared`, where you can add the code that you're sharing in testing different modules, like custom rules, test data, etc.

And then include this `test-shared` module in your other modules, using:

```
testImplementation(project(":test-shared"))
```

Google IO app uses a similar strategy: https://github.com/google/iosched/tree/master/test-shared

Answer (score 1):

You'd use the [*Gradle* test fixtures plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:java_test_fixtures) in *Java* or *Kotlin* modules:

> Test fixtures are commonly used to setup the code under test, or provide utilities aimed at facilitating the tests of a component. Java projects can enable test fixtures support by applying the `java-test-fixtures` plugin, in addition to the `java` or `java-library` plugins:

```
testImplementation testFixtures(project(':core'))
```

I'm not sure if you could define test fixtures with an *Android* module as well. Also I had small issues with *IDEA*. I tried to fix these with the `xyz.tynn.idea.fix` plugin. But mostly it's a nice tooling from *Gradle*.

You'll find a nice post by Michael Evans on [Stop Repeating Yourself: Sharing Test Code Across Android Modules](http://michaelevans.org/blog/2019/09/21/stop-repeating-yourself-sharing-test-code-across-android-modules/).

Comment: seems to be the best solution but unfortunately not a solution I can use because I use android library modules --> stared this issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/139438142 :-)